# dictionary stays the same when returning from recursion

Tags: c#, dictionary, recursion

I have this piece of code that uses recursion to calculate the sum of something on all numbers up to limit.

```
static long gen(int limit, List<int> primes,int num,int idx,myDict dict,long sum)
    {

        for (int i = idx; i < primes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (num * primes[i] > limit || num * primes[i] < 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            dict.update(primes[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-->{1}", num * primes[i], dict.maxv);
            gen(limit, primes, num * primes[i], i, dict, sum + dict.maxv);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

myDict is basically a dictionary that saves it's max value and the key to that value.

My problem is that `dict` is not changing when returning from the recursion. I mean that if for example I debug the function and in the call stack there are a few calls to this function and I try to examine the values of the variables there. `num` holds the value it should according to when it was called but dict always holds the "newest" value.

lets take an example that in the call stack the value for `num` is currently `8` and dict currently holds the values:`2:(3,4)` the dict that we should have is this. but if I examine the previous calls in the call stack I find that in all of them dict has the same value and not the value that it had when the function was could from there.

I think that maybe there is some conceptual idea that I'm not understanding correctly.

Comment: Try defining the function to pass dict by reference.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Comment: Oh whoops.  I think the answer by Johan is correct.  It's the opposite problem, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myDict` is essentially a `Dictionary`, it is always passed by reference to the `gen` method.
This means that there is only one instance of `myDict` and in every iteration of your recursive method `dict` refers to this one and only instance.
Simply returning from `gen` will pop the reference to your `myDict`from the stack, but this will not change its contents.
 If you want to return dict to its previous state, you will have to implement the backtracking yourself.

Comment: I am not sure i completely understand you, can you give a simple example.
if I'm just writing `new myDict(dict)` I think it should work but it dosen't. can you explain better what is this backtracking.

Comment: When you call 'gen', you don't really pass the Dictionary (its contents),  but only a reference (the address in memory where itis stored).
If in 'gen' you change anything in your Dictionary, and then return from the recursive call, those changes will still have happened (you are looking to the same dictionary from several different places).
So if you want to get the dictionary in its previous state, you will have to undo the changes that have been made (that's backtracking):

Comment: Or you pass an actual COPY of your dictionary.  Here's how you'd do it with a normal dictionary:  `Dictionary<int, double> copy = new Dictionary<int, double>(original);`  (leaving out the left-hand side for a function call, of course)